# Difference between using list and back tick in macros

Tags: clojure

At a conceptual level a macro in LISP (and dialects) take a piece of code (as list) and returns another piece of code (again as list).

Based on above principle a simple macro could be:

```
(defmacro zz [a] (list print a))
;macroexpand says : (#<core$print clojure.core$print@749436> "Hello")
```

But in clojure this can also be written as:

```
(defmacro zz [a] `(print ~a))
;macroexpand says : (clojure.core/print "Hello")
```

I am not exactly sure about the difference here and which should be the preferred way. The first one look simple as we are supposed to return list and avoid using weird characters like back tick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No one has pointed this out yet...the difference between your 2 macros is this: your second form (using backtick)

```
(defmacro zz [a] `(print ~a))
```

is equivalent to:

```
(defmacro zz [a] (list 'print a))
```

Which is different from your first example:

```
(defmacro zz [a] (list print a))
```

Note the missing single quote -- that is why your macroexpand is different.  I agree with the other people posting: using backquote is more conventional if your macro has a fairly simple 'shape'.  If you have to do code walking or dynamic construction (i.e. a complex macro), then using lists and building it up is often what's done.

I hope this explanation makes sense.

Comment: It's actually equivalent to `(list \`print a)`, which is slightly different: `'print` will only work if the caller has `print` referring to `clojure.core/print` rather than a local, or no binding at all (say they excluded it from the `:refer-clojure` of their namespace). `\`print`, on the other hand, expands directly to `clojure.core/print` so it is unabmiguous and correct in any context.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks for replying, based on your sugestion I just tried doing a macroexpand (via slime) on ```(print ~a)` and I got back: `(seq (concat (list 'print) (list a)))` - ah, but you're saying the pre-transformed form is more akin to having ```print` aren't you?

Comment: I can't read your response very well because SO is eating some of the backtick characters, but: Slime is hiding the namespaces from you (and macroexpand is not necessary). If you just quote the expression, by typing `'\`(print ~a)` in the repl, you see it is equivalent to `(clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote clojure.core/print)) (clojure.core/list a)))`. The `clojure.core/print` is the important distinction I was making.

Answer (score 6):

Constructing lists explicitly is "simplest", in a way, because there are few core concepts you need to know: just accept a list and change it around till you have a new list. Backtick is a convenient shortcut for "templating" chunks of code; it is possible to write any macro without it, but for any large macro it quickly becomes very unpleasant. For example, consider two ways of writing `let` as a macro over `fn`:

```
(defmacro let [bindings & body]
  (let [names (take-nth 2 bindings)
        vals (take-nth 2 (rest bindings))]
    `((fn [~@names]
        (do ~@body))
      ~@vals)))

(defmacro let [bindings & body]
  (let [names (take-nth 2 bindings)
        vals (take-nth 2 (rest bindings))]
    (cons (list `fn (vec names) (cons `do body))
          vals)))
```

In the first case, using backtick makes it fairly clear that you're writing a function of the names containing the body, and then calling it with the values - the macro code is "shaped" the same as the expansion code, so you can imagine what it will look like.

In the second case, with just `cons` and `list` all over the place, it is a real headache to work out what the expansion will look like. This isn't always the case, of course: sometimes it can be clearer to write something without a backtick.

Another very important point was made by Kyle Burton: `print` is not the same as `'print`! Your macro expansion should contain the *symbol* `print`, not its value (which is a function). Embedding objects (such as functions) in code is very fragile and only works by accident. So make sure your macros expand to code you could actually have written yourself, and let the evaluation system do the hard work - you could type in the symbol `print`, but you couldn't type in a pointer to the current value of the function `print`.

Answer (score 5):

There's a style difference between them. Your example is very simple but in more complex macros the difference will be bigger.

For example the unless macro as defined in "The Joy of Clojure" book:

```
(defmacro unless [condition & body]
    `(if (not ~condition)
        (do ~@body)))
```

From the book:

> Syntax-quote allows the following if-form to act as a sort of template for the expression
>      that any use of the macro become when it is expanded.

When creating a macro always choose the most readable and idiomatic style.

To contrast, the above code can equivalently be written like so:

```
(defmacro unless [condition & body]
  (list 'if (list 'not condition)
            (list* 'do body)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience they are equivalent.  Though there may be some edge cases I'm not aware of.

@islon 's example can equivalently be written as:

To contrast, the above code can equivalently be written like so:

```
(defmacro unless [condition & body]
  (list 'if (list 'not condition)
            (list* 'do body)))
```